# Get attribute of iterating element inside loop in xslt

Tags: css, xml, xslt, xpath

I want to know how to loop over the attribute of the looping element in xslt.
I have following xml structure:

```
<catalog>
    <cd v="1">
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd>
    <cd v="2">
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>
        <company>CBS Records</company>
        <price>9.90</price>
        <year>1988</year>
    </cd>
```

And my xslt is as follows:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
  <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="../cd/@v"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
  </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

What happens with this xslt is that, it fetches the attribute for cd from the first tag only. So for all the rows the value will be 1. How can i get it to iterate over the other attribute values also if there are more elements? Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="../cd/@v"/>
```

use simply:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@v"/>
```